# На какой платформе можно удобно работать в Python, html, css и django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, ide

Хочу определиться с своим IDE и вообще площадкой для кодинга то pycharm но в нем нету поддержки css, а sublime непонятно работает с терминалом может VS code? или еще какая-то есть IDE? Дайте совет, заранее спасибо

Comment: Только вы можете знать, что удобно лично вам

Comment: Ну и в pycharm поддержка css [очень даже есть](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/web_development.html#CSS)

Comment: И при этом тот же самый pycharm [фигово работает с терминалом](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/307), ага

Comment: В pycharm она есть но она только по блатной платной подписке

Comment: в целом, продукты от JetBrains опупительные. Но не особо понимаю как в текущих условиях получить подписку для новеньких, если только искать кряки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code нормально работает с Python и с терминалом.
Для Django есть расширения со снипетами, для быстрого написания кода.
По этому если Вам нужен легкая и гибкая IDE, то VS Code определенно Ваш выбор.